# Python Pandas - copy substring from one column to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got the following dataframe

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-9hbo{font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-9hbo">JobID</th>
    <th class="tg-9hbo">JobName</th>
    <th class="tg-9hbo">JobLink</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">n/a</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Some job name</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">https://www.particulawebsite.com/jobs-some-job-name.id123465789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">n/a</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">another job name</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">https://www.particulawebsite.com/jobs-another-job-name.id987654321</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">n/a</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">yet another name</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">https://www.particulawebsite.com/jobs-yet-another-job-name.id987321654</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is copy the id part from the JobLink column and put it in the JobID one. Haven't been able to successfully do it so far, hence my question.

Many thanks,
D

Comment: It'd be much easier if you posted the actual DataFrame instead of the HTML. If you're asking how to convert this to a DataFrame, that's entirely another question.

Comment: also, if can share what have you tried yet and what's not working

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to put a table in there, so it's easier to understand how the dataframe looks like. Will replace it with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

`df['JobID'] = df['JobLink'].map(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])`

This will store the first row for 'JobID' as 'id123465789'

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
df.JobID = df.JobLink.str.extract(r'\.id(.+)$')
```

Output:

```
0      JobID           JobName                                            JobLink
1  123465789     Some job name  https://www.particulawebsite.com/jobs-some-job...
2  987654321  another job name  https://www.particulawebsite.com/jobs-another-...
3  987321654  yet another name  https://www.particulawebsite.com/jobs-yet-anot...
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks. I was applying the extract method all wrong.